# Realm what is RealmObject.isValid()?

Tags: android, realm

Hi everybody i have somes problems or bug..
Have 1 year working with `Realm` i understand realm use threads ok..

what does it mean make isValid() for example

```
User user extends RealmObject

user.isValid() ?
```

What is my result ?

Answer (score 3):

`user.isValid()` returns whether this RealmProxy objects points to a "valid object" in the Realm, although it is easier to understand that an "object that hasn't been invalidated".

Two things invalidate a RealmObject:

- closing the Realm instance it belongs to
- deleting the object on any thread (if you're on an auto-updating looper thread)

Comment: isValid is object if exists to realm ?

Comment: If the Realm is closed or the object no longer exists in Realm

Comment: not undestand if realm is closed ? ever close realm by change

Comment: maybe i can open to `onCreate` and close for `onDestroy` ? but i have methods so ever close by each method

Comment: I always keep a Realm instance alive for the duration of the thread. It means I open/close the Realm at beginning and end of thread, or count open activities using retained fragments.